# Call BigQuery stored procedure(Routine) using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, google-bigquery

I'm trying to call a Google BigQuery stored procedure (Routine) using Spring boot. I tried all the methods of the routines to extract data. However, it didn't help.

Has anyone ever created and called a BigQuery stored procedure (Routine) through the Spring boot? If so, how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package ops.google.com;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryError;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.EncryptionConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllRequest;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.InsertAllResponse;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;


public class SelectFromBigQueryFunction {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SelectFromBigQueryFunction.class);

    public boolean tableSelectFromJoin(String key_path) {

        String projectID = "ProjectID";
        String datasetName = "DataSetName";
        String tableName1 = "sample_attribute_type";
        String tableName2 = "sample_attribute_value";

        boolean status = false;

        try {
            
            //Call BQ Function/Routines, functinon name->bq_function_name 
            //String query = String.format("SELECT DataSetName.bq_function_name(1, 1)");
            
            //Call BQ Stored Procedure, procedure name-> bq_stored_procedure_name
            String query = String.format("CALL DataSetName.bq_stored_procedure_name()");
            
            File credentialsPath = new File(key_path);
            
            FileInputStream serviceAccountStream = new FileInputStream(credentialsPath);
            
            GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccountStream);
            // Initialize client that will be used to send requests. This client only needs to be created
            
            BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
                    .setProjectId(projectID)
                    .setCredentials(credentials)
                    .build().getService();

            
             QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();

            TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);

            results.iterateAll().forEach(row -> row.forEach(val -> System.out.printf("%s,", val.toString())));
            logger.info("Query performed successfully with encryption key.");
            status = true;
        
        } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Query not performed \n" + e.toString());
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Some Exception \n" + e.toString());

        }return status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Boolean executeInsertQuery(String query, TableId tableId, String jobName) {
    log.info("Starting {} truncate query", jobName);
    BigQuery bigquery = GCPConfig.getBigQuery(); // bqClient

 

    // query configuration
    QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
            .setUseLegacySql(false)
            .setAllowLargeResults(true)
            .setDestinationTable(tableId)     .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE).build();


    try {
        // build the query job.
        QueryJob queryJob = new QueryJob.Builder(queryConfig).bigQuery(bigquery).jobName(jobName).build();

        QueryJob.Result result = queryJob.execute();
    

    } catch (JobException e) {
        log.error("{} unsuccessful. job id: {}, job name: {}. exception: {}", jobName, e.getJobId(),
                e.getJobName(), e.toString());
        return false;
    }

}
```